# Pass values from page to user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I am storing name and last name in two labels in main page. I also have those values in a class (class doesnt do much but i am using them for future expansion). I have a user control that will send an email with name and last name as body.

My question is that how can I transfer label or class variable values into user control's body variable?

Comment: In which environment that usercontrol is created?

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to ASP.NET and C#
what do you exactly mean by environment?

Comment: It mean whether the usercontrol belongs to ajax?

Comment: Nope.. its a normal ascx file with couple of text boxes & a button

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Create a property on your user control with the datatype of the data you want to pass to it, and populate it in your page on creation of the control.

```
public class myUserControl : Control
    {
      ...
      public int myIntProperty {get; set;}
      ...
    }
```

Later this in the code behind you can assign the value like

```
myUserControl cntrl = new myUserControl();
    cntrl.myIntProperty = 5;
```

Instead of this you can pass the value through Markup also like

```
<uc1:myUserControl ID="uc1" runat="server" myIntProperty="5" />
```

Comment: how do I get myIntProperty's value on page load?

Answer (score 3):

You need to create properties on your control to hold these values; then from the page code, simply assign the values to the properties in the control.

On your control, you can have something like

```
public string FirstName
{
  get {
     if (ViewState["FirstName"] == null)
        return string.Empty;
     return ViewState["FirstName"].ToString();

      }
      set {
           ViewState["FirstName"] = value;
      }
}
```

Comment: This is true. If you simply implement get/set and dont handle this right before that block `[Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), Bindable(true)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
        [Description("Some description"), Category("Misc"), DefaultValue(string.Empty)]` you will never get it working right.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define public properties on the control and then when you use control on the page you can pass values to those parameters.

Something like:

```
<cc:mycustomControl runat="server" 
    MyProperty1=<%# label1 %>
    MyProperty2=<%# label2 %>
/>
```

Comment: this way if fine when there are only couple of controls to pass
but with large number code will be messy
cant I pass the value in some other way?

Comment: Not sure I get it. Why is it messy. What do you mean pass in other way? Does it matter the exact syntax of how you pass it?

Comment: No I mean writing line for each property will make the code longer
I am still green so I am trying to go by book.. longer code, more chances of mistakes

Comment: But now that I think about it, passing value by assignment will still put a line of code anyway
I will try this one too

Comment: ok, then put them on the same line... still don't understand how you expect to pass something to a control (or function) without passing it...

Comment: No I was just being stupid
Just matched all the possible codes..different designed but essentially the same. I am passing the value.. I have to.. Dont know what was I thinking..
Thanks for the help. Really helped me sort out my problem

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** 
You can expost the values as property and than you can make use of that easily.

**Step 2:** To access your page from the user control you can make use of `Parent` property or may be some custome login to access the parent page and than write code to consume the property value.

Comment: did our answers meet midway :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this  in your user control

```
string x=((yourparentcontrol)this.parent).label1.text;
```

and use the string `x`.

Comment: tried that.. it gives me an error
Keyword 'this' is not available in the current context