# Pass Query String to User Control from Parent Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

i have create a user control search.ascx with query string values and i m accessing this page from Parent page(Rcomm.aspx) and now this Page is open from another page(view.apsx) on button click using hyperlink navigateurl. my question is that how can i pass my user control query string from view.aspx

Comment: not sure I understand your question, if you mean how to pass values from page to user control, possible duplicate of [Pass values from page to user control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117490/pass-values-from-page-to-user-control)

Answer (score 2):

A user control has access to the page's URL the same as any normal ASP.NET page does; thus, in order to retrieve the `QueryString` from the user control, the normal syntax will work:

```
Request.QueryString('key')
```

However, I consider this poor style, because I think of user controls as a modular item you can embed in ANY page: thus tying it directly to a particular querystring value seems to go against that. However you may have valid reasons for this.

I'm not sure I understand the second part of your question:

> how i make hyperlink navigate URL with query string for open my Rcomm.aspx

Could you please clarify?

**ADDITIONAL:** OK it seems to me like you have a link in your user control, and want to use a querystring value from the user control's parent page (Rcomm.aspx) to use in the link to a third page. Correct me if I am wrong.

In this case, you would read the querystring from the user control, then append to another URL using NavigateURL:

```
URL: Rcomm.aspx?field=value

(in code behind:)

Dim qs as string

qs = Request.QueryString('field')

MyHyperlink.NavigateURL = "newpage.aspx?field2=" & qs
```

Or something similar. Yes?

Comment: thanks Katstevens, my question is simple is that how i pass query string value of my user control from another page in navigaturl how i can send value because my embed page is open from another page with hyperlink navigaturl